# Faster way to find a value in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble optimizing my pandas loop. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

`higher_index=((df.COLUMN_A.values > value) & (df.COLUMN_B.values > pseudo_index)).argmax()`

With this line, I'll find the first value in COLUMN_A that is greater and has a higher index than a previous `value`. This `value` has index = pseudo_index (I stored all indexes in another column because I read somewhere that this was faster)

I need to do this process about 300000 times.

The code is good and all, but my len(df)=603188, and it takes about 7min to do 300000 iteractions.

Can someone share some light on how to improve this?

## UPDATE

It would take me ages to anonymize my data, so I did my best here

[image]

I'll try to further explain what I'm trying to achieve:

```
higher_index=((df.COLUMN_A.values > value) & (df.COLUMN_C.values > pseudo_index)).argmax()
lower_index=((df.COLUMN_B.values > value) & (df.COLUMN_C.values > pseudo_index)).argmax()

if higher_index > lower_index:
   print('nice')
else:
   print('not so nice')
```

These first two lines find me the first time a value in COLUMN_A or _B are higher than the value given in COLUMN_C.

There is a bit more nuance that I don't think I can share easily, but I can't just merge the two first lines to save some time. These operations need to be done separately

Comment: Hi. Please include a very small input sample, and the corresponding output

Comment: Can't we process all those 300000 in one go?

Comment: Iterating 300000 on a dataframe looks like a code smell. You are trying to optimize a nice and correct pandas query, while you should just try not to execute it so often.

Comment: I've updated the question trying to explain the issue further